# How to batch-split the pages of a PDF when there's multiple pages per page?

Tags: pdf, text-editor, editing

I have PDFs with two actual pages on one landscape page, like this:

[image]

I want to separate the pages so that each page has only one actual page on it. For example, the page in the image above above should be split in two and added in consecutive order to a new PDF. Each document has lots of pages with the same margins, so I want **batch processing.**

The text from the PDF should be preserved.

I know of a desktop application called [Briss](https://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/), but I need to do it on Android. Here's what Briss looks like:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify that you want PDF functionality to be retained. Deleted my answer as i could have clarified this before replying :)

Comment: @beeshyams Alright, edited.